# How can we have multiple Datepickers in Angular Material?

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I am going through this [link](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) in order to `make a datepicker on the webpage`. I have copied the following code from the mentioned link:

```
   <div class="item item-1" fxFlex="50%" fxFlexOrder="1">
      <mat-form-field>
         <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="{{'PORTAL.STARTDATE' | translate}}" type="text" formControlName="startDate" [(ngModel)]="unavailability.startDate" [readonly]="!componentPermission.writePermission">
         <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
         <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
   </div>
```

The above code work well for one datepicker but in `my application I want multiple Datepickers`.

I tried replicating the above code twice in order to have multiple datepickers on the page but I was only able to get placeholders there without any ability to select a date.

I am wondering what I changes I need to make in the above code in order to have multiple date-pickers on the webpage.

Comment: @Igor I have edited my question. Can you have a look ?

Comment: @Igor Can you downvote it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to use differnet name for them [matDatepicker]="picker1" and for another one picker 2 like this

```
<div class="item item-1" fxFlex="50%" fxFlexOrder="1">
     <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="{{'PORTAL.STARTDATE' | translate}}" type="text" formControlName="startDate" [(ngModel)]="unavailability.startDate" [readonly]="!componentPermission.writePermission">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
     </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

and for the second one

```
<div class="item item-1" fxFlex="50%" fxFlexOrder="1">
      <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker2" placeholder="{{'PORTAL.STARTDATE' | translate}}" type="text" formControlName="startDate" [(ngModel)]="unavailability.startDate" [readonly]="!componentPermission.writePermission">
           <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
           <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: I have one more quick question. Is there any logic which I can use in the code so that endDate should always be greater than startDate ?  I am using the following code in the typescript for validating the form:

  `validateForm() {
    this.unavailabilityForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'startDate': [''],
      'endDate': ['']
     });
  }`  

I am pretty sure I need to make some changes in the above code in order to get it done but I am not sure what changes I need to make.

Comment: I'm facing the same  problem even  though I have 3 different Id's for `[matDatePicker]`